# Can we be more welcoming?

Tags: discussion

I think something that may encourage users is if they are greeted with a warm welcome. The only time I really see users being welcomed is with a cookie cutter "Welcome to Skeptics!" and then being asked to provide references.

I've also seen new users ask questions or give answers without any welcome or acknowledgement that they are new, or in some cases having their first questions closed without further discussion.

Examples:

- [Does sharing a shower use less water?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7662/does-sharing-a-shower-use-less-water)
- [This answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3686/do-car-alarms-provide-a-significant-reduction-in-automobile-theft/7775#7775) to a question on car alarms preventing theft
- [This answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7701/is-it-illegal-to-refuse-us-currency-for-a-purchase/7711#7711) to a question about refusing US currency
- [Is water or tea dangerous for young infants?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7968/is-water-or-tea-dangerous-for-young-infants)

From what I have gathered on other SE sites, users with less than 10 rep are pretty much always welcomed with links or invitations to join the chat. I think it would be a good idea to adopt such a policy, esp when we have a higher standard of quality than other sites.

An example might be something like:

> Welcome to Skeptics.SE! Feel free to join the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/311/hub-of-reason), look at some
>   of the [issues being discussed in our community](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/) or participate in
>   the [topic of the week program](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/topic-of-the-week-sexuality-and-reproduction). If you have any questions, check
>   [the FAQ](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq) or ask in chat where someone will be happy to help.

That's not necessarily a great example but I think it gets the idea across.

I will start to do my part, but I think it would be good as whole if the community could be more welcoming wherever possible.

Thoughts?

Comment: FYI: Some of these examples would be helped by a new initiative we are trying - linking to a [closure FAQ](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1345/faq-my-question-was-closed-what-does-it-mean). Already, one new user with a high rep on StackOverflow accused a mod of being patronising, so it hasn't been 100% successful :-(

Comment: I've removed three of your examples: in two cases there was nothing wrong with the post (up voted, no comments on it), in the third the delete answer was actually converted to a comment - it's the software that calls those answers "deleted". We try to always leave a comment when doing so, but it's human to forget (and once they are converted, it's impossible to add a comment).

Comment: @Sklivvz: I think Sonny's point is that, if an user is new, we should comment to welcome him or her. We should not wait until he does something wrong.

Comment: @Borror0: sure, they were not valid examples of that.

Comment: @Sklivvz I don't understand why you removed the examples. I chose the examples simply because it was showing new users contributing without any real acknowledgement or welcoming. It has nothing to do with answers converted to comments or things being wrong with the post. I'm reverting the edit for that reason.

Comment: For example, while in the last example the post is upvoted, a comment welcoming Alex to the community might not have been out of place. It's a perfect example.

Comment: @SonnyOrdell: I can see reasons why you'd say that for the other two, by why is Faust's answer not a valid example?

Comment: @SonnyOrdell they were acknowledged because they were up voted, which in turn gives rep. It's the basic reward mechanism on this site. The deleted example, though was _not_ a positive contribution.

Comment: @Sklivvz I'm talking about more than up-voting. That's kind of the point I'm raising in the question.

Comment: @Borroro Faust's answer was his first and only contribution to the site. I am suggesting in such situations a welcoming comment would be beneficial.

Answer (score 2):

If any user wants to welcome new users, I encourage them to do so.

To make the task easier, there is [the pro-forma comments script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) which allows you to register pre-written comments for specific occasions, saving you the need to always rewrite the same comment over and over again. Instead, it's only a few clicks away.

For example, here's my saved comment requesting for references:

> Welcome to Skeptics! As skeptics, we require [claims to be backed by references](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5). Additionally, speculation and anecdotes are frowned upon and should be avoided. Please edit your answer accordingly.

Additionally, there is [the review tab](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/review) which allows you to spot new users' first answer or question as well as low quality content. More users checking it frequently couldn't hurt.