# Is it time to do another topic of the week?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, answers

Before we graduated, I proposed a "[topic of the week](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/topic-of-the-week-discontinued)" to focus the community on specific topics to increase the number of questions on the site.

Asking questions is always healthy but I think we could do a slightly different version this time.

Topics are proposed and chosen by the community as before (i.e. by creating and voting on a meta answer). Each week the top voted topic is chosen and removed from the list. Once a topic is chosen, e.g. "weapons", then for a week we should strive to:

1. Ask questions on the [weapons](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons) tag
2. Answer old questions, if any, on the [weapons](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons) tag
3. Review, fix, flag vote on old questions, if any, on the [weapons](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons) tag

What do you say? Does it sound like a good idea? Are there any volunteers to run this (i.e. cycle the topics, etc)

Comment: I was trying to think of some way to get our efforts focused on answering/fixing/closing old, highly voted questions. I think point 3 is a good way to do that.

Comment: I volunteer to cycle the topics. I'd suggest "psychology" as the first topic based on this: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology?sort=unanswered&pagesize=50

Comment: @Sancho - I think a lot of that needs sifting through for good and bad.

Comment: Should we also be deleting answers that have had a "No citations" yellow text warning for a long while and haven't been fixed?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm sure, there's even a [meta post](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1849/lets-clean-up-the-post-notices) and a [specific page](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/annotated-posts?tab=noticed).

Answer (score 3):

I really like this idea (I liked it when it was first suggested); as a way to clear up the broken windows *as well as* a way to promote and encourage new interesting questions it's even better.

If this gets more community support I'm definitely in!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's hard to get your brain wrapped around all the topics treated with such credulity in the media and on-line. It would be a great way to get people interested and involved.