# Topic of the week: Discontinued

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, answers, unanswered-questions

As proposed by [Sklivvz](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/96/sklivvz) in [this question](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2486/is-it-time-to-do-another-topic-of-the-week) we are going to be running a topic of the week.

The main aim of this is three-fold

1. To focus the community on specific topics to increase the number of questions on the site
2. To get some answers to old questions
3. To Review, fix, flag vote on old questions

---

### Rules

A slight change from [last time we did topic of the week](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/topic-of-the-week-discontinued), we want to be able to focus on points 2 & 3 above, as well as 1, so suggestions should be accompanied by the relevant main-site tag (markdown `[tag:tagnamehere]`).

- One topic per answer accompanied by its associated tag. You may also include details of questions which would benefit from a clean up and new questions you think might be suitable.
- Up vote if you think the topic is good and will generate a lot of good questions, answers and has scope for a good clean up. Down vote otherwise.
- Every Sunday evening the top topic will be chosen/announced and removed from the list (1st topic will be chosen on Sunday 1st September 2013 to allow some ramp-up time)

Answer (score 1):

## Psychology

[psychology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology)

There are 25 unanswered questions tagged [psychology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology). And, everyone's got a mind, so everyone thinks they're an expert.

Answer (score 1):

## Herbalism

[herbalism](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/herbalism) has four questions that need an answer, but aside from that there has to be a bunch of really shady claims regading herbs. For example:

- Does tilia have any relaixing effects over placebo?
- Is willow bark a viable alternative to aspirine?
- Is artichoke an effective hung-over remedy?

and so on.